# C++: How to implement polymorphic object creator to populate a table

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a table widget object that can be resized with `set_num_col(int)` and `set_num_row(int)`.
A call to each of these functions will call a `resize_table()` function to populate the widget with `table_cell`s objects.
However, I have two polymorphic types of cells: `table_cell_default` and `table_cell_custom`, derived from the same base class.
Upon creation of the table, how can I populate it with mixed types of cells, considering that the client knows which cells will be custom and which will be of default type?

I thought about adding a map in the table class, and populate this map with for example `set_custom_cells( vector<index>() )`, with the `ij` indices of the cells as keys and the corresponding lamda creator returning the correct type as value, but this map will only be used once to populate the table and never again. Is there a more dynamic way, using a lambda as a table_cell creator to fill that widget in a better way?

Thanks

Comment: Can you have the caller who is creating the table widget pass in a factory lambda which is used to construct the cell object in the table, passing in the col and row parameters?  That way, the caller can figure out (as expressed in the lambda) how to initialize the cells of the table.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for your comment! Can you please help me with how the factory lambda will look like? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of using a *factory lambda* to produce the initial cells in the Table's constructor.  Refer to `main` function where the lambda is located, and the Table constructor for how it is used.

I do not know what your code looks like, so I just wrap each cell into an object_t and put that into the Table.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Not idempotent.  Should be last include.
#include <cassert>

using std::cout;
using std::function;
using std::make_shared;
using std::move;
using std::ostream;
using std::shared_ptr;
using std::size_t;
using std::string;
using std::stringstream;
using std::vector;

namespace {

template <typename T>
void draw_right_justified(T const& x, ostream& out, size_t width) {
    stringstream ss;
    ss << x;
    string s = ss.str();
    size_t pad_width = s.length() < width ? width - s.length() : 1;
    out << string(pad_width, ' ') << s;
}

class object_t {
public:
    template <typename T>
    object_t(T x) : self_{make_shared<model<T>>(move(x))}
    { }

    friend void draw_right_justified(object_t const& x, ostream& out, size_t width) {
        x.self_->draw_right_justified_thunk(out, width);
    }

private:
    struct concept_t {
        virtual ~concept_t() = default;
        virtual void draw_right_justified_thunk(ostream&, size_t) const = 0;
    };

    template <typename T>
    struct model : concept_t {
        model(T x) : data_{move(x)} { }

        void draw_right_justified_thunk(ostream& out, size_t width) const {
            draw_right_justified(data_, out, width);
        }

        T data_;
    };

    shared_ptr<const concept_t> self_;
};

class Table {
    size_t col;
    size_t row;
    // data will be constructed with col_ * row_ entries.
    vector<object_t> data;
public:
    using object_factory = function<object_t(size_t, size_t)>;
    Table(size_t col_, size_t row_, object_factory& fn);
    auto operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const -> object_t;
    void display(ostream& out) const;
};

Table::Table(size_t col_, size_t row_, Table::object_factory& fn)
    : col{col_}, row{row_}
{
    data.reserve(col * row);
    for (size_t y = 0; y < row; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < row; ++x) {
            data.emplace_back(fn(x, y));
        }
    }
}

object_t Table::operator()(size_t x, size_t y) const {
    assert(x < col);
    assert(y < row);
    return data[y * row + x];
}

void Table::display(ostream& out) const {
    auto const& self = *this;
    for (size_t y = 0; y < row; ++y) {
        for (size_t x = 0; x < col; ++x) {
            draw_right_justified(self(x, y), out, 8);
        }
        out << "\n";
    }
}

struct empty_t {};

void draw_right_justified(empty_t, ostream& out, size_t width) {
    string s = "(empty)";
    size_t pad_width = s.length() < width ? width - s.length() : 1;
    out << string(pad_width, ' ') << s;
}

struct bunny { string name; };

void draw_right_justified(bunny const& bunny, ostream& out, size_t width) {
    auto const& s = bunny.name;
    size_t pad_width = s.length() < width ? width - s.length() : 1;
    out << string(pad_width, ' ') << s;
}

} // anon

int main() {
    Table::object_factory maker = [](size_t x, size_t y) {
        if (x == 0 && y == 1) return object_t{bunny{"Bugs"}};
        if (x == 0 && y == 0) return object_t{empty_t{}};
        if (x == y) return object_t{string("EQUAL")};
        return object_t{x * y};
    };

    auto table = Table{3, 5, maker};
    table.display(cout);
}
```

Output...

```
 (empty)       0       0
    Bugs   EQUAL       2
       0       2   EQUAL
       0       3       6
       0       4       8
```

Comment: Thank you so much! such a clear example! I really appreciate that

Comment: I used Sean Parent's static polymorphism technique.  Dynamic polymorphism is intrusive, and not possible to add virtual functions to (say) `int`.  Unfortunately, static polymorphism requires a little bit of boilerplate infrastructure code.  I didn't take time to refactor out all the technical debt in this code example.