# Best way to store an initializer list in a polymorphic vector

Tags: c++

Given the following scenario

```
template <typename T> struct Parent {};
template <typename T> struct Child : Parent<T> {};

struct Bar
{
  vector<???> stuff;
  Bar(initializer_list<Parent<T>> things)
  {
    // store things as stuff
  }
};
```

I want to be able to write

```
Parent<int> parent;
Child<int> child;
Bar bar{parent, child};
```

My question: what's the best way to polymorphically keep the initializer list? If I wanted to, say, keep it as `vector<unique_ptr<Parent<T>>`, what would be the best way to copy it from `things` to `stuff`?

Comment: With `std::initializer_list<Parent<T>>` you'll have [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing).

Comment: As an alternative to using an *initialization list*, you could consider using a [*factory lambda*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116).  The example has a Table with object containers that contain the types, using Sean Parent's static polymorphism technique, which isn't germane to your question -- but may also be an interesting alternative to CRTP polymorphism for your actual code.

Comment: See [doc](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list): "`std::initializer_list` is a lightweight proxy object that provides access to an array of objects of type `const T`". This means that storing it in any container may lead to situation when copy of this list will point to array which lifetime has ended so you will have UB.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing to note is that `std::initializer_list<Parent<T>>` will result in [object slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4403726/learning-c-polymorphism-and-slicing) if some elements are initialized with `Child<T>` because the underlying array would hold `Parent<T>` objects.

There could be different solutions. For example, you could use a variadic template for the constructor to avoid slicing:

```
template<typename T>
struct Bar {
  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Parent<T>>> stuff;
  
  template<typename... Us>
  Bar(Us... us) {
      stuff.reserve(sizeof...(Us));
      (stuff.push_back(std::make_unique<Us>(std::move(us))), ...);
  }
};
```

Here, `(stuff.push_back(), ...)` is a fold-expression that will be expanded into a sequence of `push_back` calls for each element of the `us` pack. Due to the const-ness of the `initializer_list` underlying array we [can't do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8468817)

```
Bar(Us... us) : stuff{std::make_unique<Us>(std::move(us))...}
{}
```

---

With C++17 deduction guides we can simplify the syntax a little bit.

```
template<typename> struct TypeTrait {};
template<typename T> struct TypeTrait<Parent<T>> { using Type = T; };
template<typename T> struct TypeTrait<Child<T>>  { using Type = T; };

template<typename... Us>
Bar(Us...) -> Bar<std::common_type_t<typename TypeTrait<Us>::Type...>>;
```

Now we don't need to specify the template parameter explicitly, it will be deduced:

```
Parent<int> parent;
Child<int> child;
Bar bar{parent, child};   // T deduces to int
```

(If the member type `Type` could be put into `Parent` directly, a helper struct `TypeTrait` is not needed.)

Comment: This works. The only (tiny) downside is you have to init the thing as Bar<int>(a, b, c) rather than Bar(a, b, c) — would be great if the thing could infer the type argument. Sadly seems it cannot.

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk `std::vector` should know the type of elements to hold, and this type should be specified as a template parameter. What you could do is to introduce a non-template `ParentBase`, derive `Parent<T>` from it and then use `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ParentBase>>` as a container. If the only concern is the syntax (the necessity to add `<int>`) but not the formal template parameter `Bar` has, this could be solved using a deduction guide and some template metaprogramming tricks.