# Check casting from void* to a known type is safe

Tags: c++, templates, casting, void

I want to pass free-form data between classes using a fifo of objects. This is the FIFO object:

```
class FifoObject final
{
public:
    FifoObject() {};

    template<typename T>
    FifoObject(std::unique_ptr<T>& obj):
        freeData(static_cast<void*>(obj.release())),
        deleteObject([](void* data) {delete(static_cast<T*>(data));})
    {

    }

    ~FifoObject()
    {
        if (freeData != nullptr) {deleteObject(freeData);}
    }

    template<typename T>
    inline T* release() 
    {
        T* retVal = static_cast<T*>(freeData); // how can I check this cast is valid?
        freeData = nullptr; 
        return retVal;
    }

private:
    void* freeData = nullptr;
    std::function<void(void* data)> deleteObject;
};
```

**How it works**: It stores the object in a temporary `void*` pointer. It can release the object with `released()` function. In case it isn't used, the destroyer will kill the `void*` using the lambda.

**My question is**: in the `release()` function, how could I assert & type-check the static_cast to make sure I'm casting to a valid type (including derived/base types)?

**Notes**

1. FifoObject cannot be a template (it's inside an array).
2. I may inherit the objects I place inside from a common dummy class and use dynamic_cast to check if the static_cast is going to be OK. But I'm looking for a neater way to do it (I have too many classes).
3. I cannot use a `shared_ptr<void>` instead of a `void*`, since it hasn't a "release" method.
4. I cannot use a `std::any` either, it hasn't a "release".
5. Using a `std::variant` instead a `void*` is too much for me. I have around two hundreds of different object type pointers. The cost of maintenance is high.
6. I've seen, `std::any_cast` does a type-check to an `std::any` object. I tried to look inside its code, but I cannot replicate it for this function.
7. I've been actively searching other post in stack-overflow about this topic before asking. However they seem quite old, and maybe there is now a way to do it with C++20.
8. Wouldn't be great if you may save as a member variable a class's name in C++? :)

Comment: Using void pointer is giving up any type safety which C++ provides. If your class design requires this then your class design is broken (in 99 of 100 use cases).

Comment: _8. Wouldn't be great if you may save as a member variable a class's name in C++?_ This is type reflection. The only kind of type reflection which is available until C++20 is the [RTTI](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types) but this might be even sufficient for your purpose.

Comment: I used static polymorphism to do something similar in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116).  If you kept the type in the same way that Table keeps a vector of object_t, and object_t wraps the type with a concept_t holder interface, which holds onto the actual type using a template model derived from concept_t... you could get rid of `void*` altogether.

Comment: You know what `T` is inside the constructor, and you've written code that preserves that knowledge (with that lambda). Do the same thing to restore the `T*` and use that inside the `release()` function. I'd use a different name for the template argument to `release()`, since it's not necessarily the same type as the `T` in the constructor. So `release<U>()` would convert the `void*` to `T*` and return that. If the conversion from `T*` to `U*` isn't valid, the compiler will complain.

Comment: @PeteBecker thanks for the reply. I tried that before. However in order to make an std::function returns a T*, I need to have a member variable it in this way: ´std::function<T*(void)> createObject´ which would requires I convert to a template FifoObject.

Comment: @Eljay, thanks I will take a look now!

Comment: @JuanJuezSarmiento -- you're right. Sorry...