# How to identify elements in array or matrix and work with them correctly? c++

Tags: c++, class, oop, inheritance

First, i have got abstract parent class:

```
class Abstract_class {
  virtual void Method1() {
   std::cout<<"Method1 of abstract class!\n";
  }
};
```

also i have a child classes

```
class Child1: public Abstract_class {
  void Method1() override {
    std::cout<<"Method1 of child1 class!\n";
  }
};

class Child2: public Abstract_class {
  void Method1() override {
    std::cout<<"Method1 of child2 class!\n";
  }
};
```

My main function

```
int main(){
   Abstract_class ** arr = new Abstract_class * [10];
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j<10; j++) {
     Abstract_class * obj;
     // pseudo random rules for fill array
     if (i%2 == 0) {
       arr[i] = new Child1();
     }
     else {
       arr[i] = new Child2();
     }
    }
  }
}
```

Now, let's say I perform some action with this array, refer to the elements, and I need to know which one, where the object is located, so that there is no situation where I expect Method1 to be executed as in child1, but I get a completely different implementation of the child2 method.
Of course, you can always add fields to classes to identify an object, but I would like something elegant according to the rules of OOP

UPD1:

So, I realized that this way of working with objects in polymorphism is wrong. But suppose we have a certain playing field on which there are different heir objects (box, enemy, player), how can they be on the same field if they are of different types. How can I interact with them?

Comment: One of the key points to polymorphism is that the function *using* a polymorphic type does **not** have to be aware of what type it is working with.  Having code that needs that is probably an architectural bug, and a violation of LSP.

Comment: @Eljay Ok, I just can't think of a better method for storing a matrix with different elements. Let's say we have a certain playing field on which there are different heir objects (box, enemy, player), how are they able to be on the same field if they are of different types?

Comment: An answer I provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116) leverages CRTP and *static polymorphism* in a table comprised of different types.  (The answer has had up votes and down votes, so it's not a widely approved of answer.  Probably answered too far afield from the question, even though the OP was appreciative of the answer.)  Maybe that kind of technique would be of use for your program.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dynamic cast for this:

```
Abstract_class *someObj = ...;
if(Child1 *c1 = dynamic_cast<Child1>(someObj)) {
    c1->specificChild1Func();
}
```

However, you shouldn't *need* something like this. The point of polymorphism is that you can have no idea what the underlying type is, but still work with them all the same. The fact that you're looking for this is likely a sign that you need to work on your design.

Comment: Yes, but how can I work with, say, a field (albeit playable), on which there are different types of objects: Player, enemies, boxes, etc.

Comment: @Sss What are you trying to do with that field? Something like collision detection? In that case, polymorphism should have you covered. You should have some `bool isCollisionDetected()` on each of those classes and you can use polymorphism to call the right one.