# Friend function not found by inner class in Type Erasure setup C++

Tags: c++, type-erasure, argument-dependent-lookup, friend-function

I watched Klaus Iglberger give a great talk at CppCon 2021 about Type Erasure. I went to set up the pattern myself based on his example. His External Polymorphic piece dispatched to a friend function of an outer class. That piece is not compiling for me.

I've tried shuffling around the order of definition and pulling the implementation of the friend function outside the class. I didn't set up an implementation file yet because I wasn't very convinced that would be a solution.

I'm using GCC 9.3 and Clang 10. Errors look the same. Clang10:
`type_erasure_example.cpp:57:22: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 0, have 1 serialize( object );`

`type_erasure_example.cpp:61:28: error: too many arguments to function call, expected 2, have 3 draw( object, x, y );`

GCC9.3:

`type_erasure_example.cpp:57:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Shape::ShapeModel<Square>::serialize(const Square&) const’ 57 |           serialize( object );`

`type_erasure_example.cpp:61:11: error: no matching function for call to ‘Shape::ShapeModel<Square>::draw(const Square&, int&, int&) const’ 61 |           draw( object, x, y );`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Circle 
{ 
 public: 
   explicit Circle( double rad ) 
      : radius{ rad } 
      // ... Remaining data members 
   {} 
   double getRadius() const noexcept { return radius; }
   // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
 private: 
   double radius; 
   // ... Remaining data members 
};

class Square 
{ 
 public: 
   explicit Square( double s ) 
      : side{ s } 
      // ... Remaining data members 
   {} 
   double getSide() const noexcept { return side; }
   // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
 private: 
   double side; 
   // ... Remaining data members 
};

class Shape 
{ 
 private:
    struct ShapeConcept 
    { 
       virtual ~ShapeConcept() {} 
       virtual void serialize() const = 0; 
       virtual void draw(int x, int y) const = 0; 
       virtual std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const = 0; 
    }; 

    template< typename T > 
    struct ShapeModel : ShapeConcept 
    { 
       ShapeModel( T&& value ) 
          : object{ std::forward<T>(value) } 
       {} 
       
       std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const override 
       { 
          return std::make_unique<ShapeModel>(*this); 
       } 
       void serialize() const override 
       { 
          serialize( object ); // Error
       } 
       void draw( int x, int y ) const override 
       { 
          draw( object, x, y ); // Error
       } 
       T object; 
    };

    friend void serialize( Shape const& shape )
    { 
       shape.pimpl->serialize(); 
    }
    friend void draw( Shape const& shape, int x, int y )
    { 
       shape.pimpl->draw( x, y ); 
    }

    std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> pimpl; 
 public: 
   template< typename T > 
   Shape( T&& x ) 
      : pimpl{ new ShapeModel<T>( std::forward<T>(x) ) } 
   {} 
   // Special member functions 
   Shape( Shape const& s ); 
   Shape( Shape&& s ); 
   Shape& operator=( Shape const& s ); 
   Shape& operator=( Shape&& s ); 
};


void serialize( Circle const& circle ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a circle with radius "
        << circle.getRadius() << std::endl;
} 
void draw( Circle const& circle, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a circle with radius "
        << circle.getRadius() << " Coordinates ("
        << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
void serialize( Square const& square ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a square with side "
        << square.getSide() << std::endl;
} 
void draw( Square const& square, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a square with side "
        << square.getSide() << " Coordinates ("
        << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
} 

void drawAllShapes( std::vector<Shape> const& shapes ) 
{ 
   for( auto const& shape : shapes ) 
   { 
      draw( shape , 0.0, 0.0 ); 
   } 
}
int main() 
{ 
   using Shapes = std::vector<Shape>; 
   // Creating some shapes 
   Shapes shapes; 
   shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 2.0 } ); 
   shapes.emplace_back( Square{ 1.5 } ); 
   shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 4.2 } ); 
   // Drawing all shapes 
   drawAllShapes( shapes ); 
}
```

Comment: Please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* error output into your question. And add comments in the code where you get the errors.

Comment: With [look-up rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup#Member_function_definition), `void serialize() const override { serialize( object );}` founds only the members of the class (before ADL can take effect).

Comment: If you want to see another example, because it is a bit mind blowing, you may want to review my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116 . (I got your code to work by changing the name to `fwd_serialize`, and you got it to work by `::serialize`.)

Comment: @Jarod42 why does lookup stop then? Is it because the lookup set is not empty once it finds `ShapeModel::serializa()`, even if the signature doesn't match?

Comment: [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) also states *"First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
1) a declaration of a class member"*.

Answer (score 2):

Someone posted in the comments and it set me on the right track. I didn't understand the setup well enough. The friend classes *were* being handled right. It was the free functions that needed re-arranging. An implementation file would've helped afterall, and we can do it header-only:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Circle 
{ 
 public: 
   explicit Circle( double rad ) 
      : radius{ rad } 
      // ... Remaining data members 
   {} 
   double getRadius() const noexcept { return radius; }
   // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
 private: 
   double radius; 
   // ... Remaining data members 
};

class Square 
{ 
 public: 
   explicit Square( double s ) 
      : side{ s } 
      // ... Remaining data members 
   {} 
   double getSide() const noexcept { return side; }
   // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
 private: 
   double side; 
   // ... Remaining data members 
};

void serialize( Circle const& circle ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a circle with radius "
        << circle.getRadius() << std::endl;
} 
void draw( Circle const& circle, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a circle with radius "
        << circle.getRadius() << " Coordinates ("
        << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
void serialize( Square const& square ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a square with side "
        << square.getSide() << std::endl;
} 

void draw( Square const& square, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a square with side "
        << square.getSide() << " Coordinates ("
        << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
} 

class Shape 
{ 
 private:
    struct ShapeConcept 
    { 
       virtual ~ShapeConcept() {} 
       virtual void serialize() const = 0; 
       virtual void draw(int x, int y) const = 0; 
       virtual std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const = 0; 
    }; 

    template< typename T > 
    struct ShapeModel : ShapeConcept 
    { 
       ShapeModel( T&& value ) 
          : object{ std::forward<T>(value) } 
       {} 
       
       std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const override 
       { 
          return std::make_unique<ShapeModel>(*this); 
       } 
       void serialize() const override 
       { 
          ::serialize( object ); 
       } 
       void draw( int x, int y ) const override 
       { 
          ::draw( object, x, y ); 
       } 
       T object; 
    };

    friend void serialize( Shape const& shape )
    { 
       shape.pimpl->serialize(); 
    }
    friend void draw( Shape const& shape, int x, int y )
    { 
       shape.pimpl->draw( x, y ); 
    }

    std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> pimpl; 
 public: 
   template< typename T > 
   Shape( T&& x ) 
      : pimpl{ new ShapeModel<T>( std::forward<T>(x) ) } 
   {} 
   // Special member functions 
   Shape( Shape const& s ) = default;
   Shape( Shape&& s ) = default;
   Shape& operator=( Shape const& s ) = default;
   Shape& operator=( Shape&& s ) = default;
};


void drawAllShapes( std::vector<Shape> const& shapes ) 
{ 
   for( auto const& shape : shapes ) 
   { 
      draw( shape , 0.0, 0.0 ); 
   } 
}
int main() 
{ 
   using Shapes = std::vector<Shape>; 
   // Creating some shapes 
   Shapes shapes; 
   shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 2.0 } ); 
   shapes.emplace_back( Square{ 1.5 } ); 
   shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 4.2 } ); 
   // Drawing all shapes 
   drawAllShapes( shapes ); 
}
```

Comment: Yeah that was my comment, but I overlooked the free functions at the bottom that's why I deleted it again. I'm wondering why scope resolution is required here, not sure when ADL kicks in.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for your code, but I think you forgot to properly define the Copy Constructor and Assignment Operator of Shape using clone() so you can treat a Shape as a value as Klaus Iglberger suggested. I've added this together with a scale() function to test this in main().

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class Circle 
{ 
public: 
    explicit Circle( double rad ) 
        : radius{ rad } 
          // ... Remaining data members 
    {} 
    double getRadius() const noexcept { return radius; }
    void setRadius(double rad) noexcept { radius=rad; }
    // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
private: 
    double radius; 
    // ... Remaining data members 
};

class Square 
{ 
public: 
    explicit Square( double s ) 
        : side{ s } 
          // ... Remaining data members 
    {} 
    double getSide() const noexcept { return side; }
    void setSide(double s) noexcept { side=s; }
    // ... getCenter(), getRotation(), ... 
private: 
    double side; 
    // ... Remaining data members 
};

void serialize( Circle const& circle ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a circle with radius "
              << circle.getRadius() << std::endl;
} 
void draw( Circle const& circle, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a circle with radius "
              << circle.getRadius() << " Coordinates ("
              << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
}
void scale( Circle& circle, double scale_factor ) {
    circle.setRadius( circle.getRadius() * scale_factor );
}

void serialize( Square const& square ) {
    std::cout << "Serializing a square with side "
              << square.getSide() << std::endl;
} 
void draw( Square const& square, int x, int y ) {
    std::cout << "Drawing a square with side "
              << square.getSide() << " Coordinates ("
              << x << ", " << y << ")" << std::endl;
} 
void scale( Square& square, double scale_factor ) {
    square.setSide( square.getSide() * scale_factor );
}


class Shape 
{ 
private:
    struct ShapeConcept 
    { 
        virtual ~ShapeConcept() {} 
        virtual void serialize() const = 0; 
        virtual void draw(int x, int y) const = 0; 
        virtual std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const = 0;
        virtual void scale(double scale_factor)=0;
    }; 

    template< typename T > 
    struct ShapeModel : ShapeConcept 
    { 
        ShapeModel( T&& value ) 
            : object{ std::forward<T>(value) } 
        {} 
       
        std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> clone() const override 
        { 
            return std::make_unique<ShapeModel>(*this); 
        } 
        void serialize() const override 
        { 
            ::serialize( object ); 
        } 
        void draw( int x, int y ) const override 
        { 
            ::draw( object, x, y ); 
        }
        void scale(double scale_factor) override
        {
            ::scale(object,scale_factor);
        }
        T object; 
    };

    friend void serialize( Shape const& shape )
    { 
        shape.pimpl->serialize(); 
    }
    friend void draw( Shape const& shape, int x, int y )
    { 
        shape.pimpl->draw( x, y ); 
    }
    friend void scale( Shape& shape, double scale_factor)
    { 
        shape.pimpl->scale(scale_factor); 
    }
    
    std::unique_ptr<ShapeConcept> pimpl; 
public: 
    template< typename T > 
    Shape( T&& x ) 
        : pimpl{ new ShapeModel<T>( std::forward<T>(x) ) } 
    {} 
    // Special member functions
    Shape( Shape const& s ) : pimpl{ s.pimpl->clone() } {}
    Shape& operator=( Shape const& s ) { this->pimpl = s.pimpl->clone(); return *this; }
    Shape( Shape&& s ) = default;
    Shape& operator=( Shape&& s ) = default;
};

void drawAllShapes( std::vector<Shape> const& shapes ) 
{ 
    for( auto const& shape : shapes ) 
    { 
        draw( shape , 0.0, 0.0 ); 
    } 
}

int main() 
{ 
    using Shapes = std::vector<Shape>; 

    // Creating some shapes 
    Shapes shapes; 
    shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 2.0 } ); 
    shapes.emplace_back( Square{ 1.5 } ); 
    shapes.emplace_back( Circle{ 4.2 } ); 

    // Drawing all shapes 
    drawAllShapes( shapes );

    // Copying and scaling all shapes
    auto shapes_scaled = shapes; // copy shapes, here clone() is used
    for ( auto& shape : shapes_scaled )
        scale( shape, 10 );
    drawAllShapes( shapes_scaled ); // scaled by factor 10
    drawAllShapes( shapes );        // left untouched
}
```

Comment: Copy part does not compile on VS2019 - type_erasure.cpp(95,1): error C2665: 'scale': none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types

Comment: For this line "auto shapres_scaled = shapes" It looks like GCC is calling copy constructor "Shape(Shape const& s)" for each element while clang and msvc call the templated constructor "Shape(T&& x)"

Answer (score 2):

To complete the example with the kind help of Klaus
I fixed the copy/move/assign issues by adding a trait and constrain on the templated constructor based on @bterwijn post

```
...
class Shape;
template< typename T >
struct IsShape : public std::is_same< Shape, std::decay_t<T> >
{};

...
template<typename T, typename = std::enable_if_t<!IsShape<T>::value>> 
Shape( T&& x ) : pimpl{ new ShapeModel<T>( std::forward<T>(x) ) }  { }
```

Here is a complete working example (Tested on GCC, CLANG and MSVC)
https://wandbox.org/permlink/BvOngSRPXtEnFPMR

Note there are no checks on empty shapes (i.e. pimpl == nullptr)