# is it possible to use a method's return value as template parameter for another method in c++?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, polymorphism, function-templates

**[Very brief explanation]**

Is it possible to call a class's template method using another method's call's return as its template parameter?

Let's say I have a class like this:

```
//myClass.hh

myClass
{
    private:
    public:
    int getType();
    template<int i>
    someReturnType cast();
    
};
```

I want to be able to do the following:

```
//main.cpp

myClass obj;
obj.cast<obj.getType()>();
```

**[Very long explanation]**

I'm working on a list which can hold nodes of different types of data. I've successfully managed to implement the nodes.

In order for the list class to be able to hold different types of nodes (nodes holding different data type), I have created the node class in the following way:

```
//Node.hh
class voidNode
{
    private:
    public:
        const TypeID _type;
        NodeNumber _nodeNumber;
        voidNode *_next;
        explicit voidNode(const TypeID id) : _type(id), _next(nullptr), _nodeNumber(0) { };
        virtual ~voidNode() { };
        virtual const TypeID getNodeType() = 0;
};

template<class dataType>
class Node : public voidNode
{
    private:
        dataType _data;
    public:
        explicit Node() {   }
        explicit Node(const dataType &data, const NodeNumber &n = 0) : _data(data), voidNode(GetTypeID<dataType>::_typeID) {  _nodeNumber = n; };
        virtual ~Node() { };
        void setData(const dataType &data) { _data = data; }
        dataType getData() { return _data; };
        NodeNumber getNodeNumber() { return _nodeNumber; }
        const TypeID getNodeType() override { return _type; }
        friend class singleList;
};
template<std::size_t N> Node(char const (&)[N], const NodeNumber (&)) -> Node<char const*>;
```

Details aside, this implementations works ok for the given time, I can instantiate nodes like:

```
//main.cpp
char *cStyleString = "c style string";
const char *constantCStyleString = "constant c style string";
const char ff = 'A';
float dec = 98.99;
uint32_t uintN{987};
int32_t intN{-97};
bool BoolT{true};

Node node1(uintN);
Node node2(intN);
Node node3(BoolT);
Node node4((uint)87);
Node node5(-999);
Node node6(false);
Node node7('c');
Node node8("hola",0);
Node node9(cStyleString, 0);
Node node10(ff, 0);
Node node11(dec, 0);

std::cout << node1.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node2.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node3.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node4.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node5.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node6.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node7.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node8.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node9.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node10.getData() << std::endl;
std::cout << node11.getData() << std::endl;
```

And get an output like:

[image]

In the list class. I'm storing the nodes using their base class, so I've provided the class with a method for casting the base class to the correct derived class:

```
//list.hh
class singleList
{
    private:

    //Base class for nodes.
    voidNode *_start{nullptr};
    voidNode *_current{nullptr};
    voidNode *_last{nullptr};

    public:
    template<class ...Args>
    explicit singleList(const Args &...args);
    ~singleList();

    /**this method returns the base class ptr casted
      *to one of its derived classes, depending on 
      *the template parameter "i". I.e, i = 0 returns Node<bool>*, 
      *i = 1 returns Node<char>*, etc. 
    */
    template<int i>
    Node<typename getType<i, _types>::_type> *nodeCast(voidNode *node)
    {
        return reinterpret_cast<Node<typename getType<i, _types>::_type>*>(node);
    }

    //Same method as above, but takes "TypeID" type instead of int
    template<const TypeID ID>
    Node<typename getType<static_cast<int>(ID), _types>::_type> *getElement(voidNode *node)
    {
        return getType<static_cast<int>(ID)>(node);
    }

};
```

This is my questioning: Since each node has a member for identifying its type of data, I would like to use "getElement" method like this:

```
//main.cpp
singleList mylist(BoolT, intN, uintN, dec, constantCStyleString);
mylist.getElement<mylist._current->getNodeType()>(mylist._current);
```

However, I get the following compile time error:

```
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:40:52: error: the value of ‘mylist’ is not usable in a constant expression
[build]    40 |     mylist.getElement<mylist._current->getNodeType()>(mylist._current);
[build]       |                                                    ^
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:39:16: note: ‘mylist’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
[build]    39 |     singleList mylist(BoolT, intN, uintN, dec, constantCStyleString);
[build]       |                ^~~~~~
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:40:54: error: no matching function for call to ‘singleList::getElement<mylist.singleList::_current->voidNode::getNodeType()>(voidNode*&)’
[build]    40 |     mylist.getElement<mylist._current->getNodeType()>(mylist._current);
[build]       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] In file included from /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:2:
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/singleList.hh:58:70: note: candidate: ‘template<TypeID ID> Node<typename getType<static_cast<int>(ID), TypeList<void, bool, char, char*, unsigned char, signed char, short unsigned int, short int, unsigned int, int, float> >::_type>* singleList::getElement(voidNode*)’
[build]    58 |         Node<typename getType<static_cast<int>(ID), _types>::_type> *getElement(voidNode *node)
[build]       |                                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/singleList.hh:58:70: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:40:54: error: the value of ‘mylist’ is not usable in a constant expression
[build]    40 |     mylist.getElement<mylist._current->getNodeType()>(mylist._current);
[build]       |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:39:16: note: ‘mylist’ was not declared ‘constexpr’
[build]    39 |     singleList mylist(BoolT, intN, uintN, dec, constantCStyleString);
[build]       |                ^~~~~~
[build] /home/inumaki/Development/cppWorkspace/secondProject/main.cpp:40:51: note: in template argument for type ‘TypeID’
[build]    40 |     mylist.getElement<mylist._current->getNodeType()>(mylist._current);
[build]       |                       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~
```

I've tried to follow the compiler's advice and make those expressions into constexpr, but that led to a lot of other errors that would just make this post longer and I think actually is not the appropriate approach, so I will not post it unless someone requires.

Thanks in advance for reading.

Comment: The short answer is **no**, you can't do that.  The long answer is **yes**, you can do that, but you are going about it all wrong and it will require constant expressions because otherwise that cannot be dynamically determined at runtime, and the long answer probably won't solve your problem.

Comment: Can you please point a little bit about what the right direction would be? thanks

Comment: Perhaps **static polymorphism**.  Perhaps `std::variant` or `std::any`.  Perhaps a container object that holds properties.  Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116

Comment: Would you mind providing a **mwe** ？I am having trouble compiling your code.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @Nimrod sorry about that, I didn't post the full implementation of some templated functions, but I'll try editing the post so I can I include what I just said.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is possible, but you are not doing it the right way...

All the tools needed are available in the stl, using std::variant.

Example:

```
#include <list>
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>  // std::quoted

// useful helpers for std::variant.

template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;


using MyTypes = std::variant<unsigned long, int, float, double, std::string>;
using MyListT = std::list<MyTypes>;

int main() {

    MyListT lst;

    lst.push_back(123);
    lst.push_back("hello");
    lst.push_back(12.3);
    lst.push_back(4.56f);
    lst.push_back(125ul);

    for (auto& e : lst)
    {
        std::visit(overloaded {
            [](auto arg) { std::cout << arg << ' '; },
            [](double arg) { std::cout << std::fixed << arg << ' '; },
            [](const std::string& arg) { std::cout << std::quoted(arg) << ' '; }
        }, e);
        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Program output:

```
123 
"hello" 
12.300000 
4.560000 
125
```

You'll find a prototype to play with here: https://godbolt.org/z/zd6az8dM1

To call a template, use auto, as in:

```
template <typename T>
void PrintType(const T& t) {
    // you could check for types this way
    // although using std::visit is recommended.
    using Type = std::remove_cv<T>::type;
    if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, int>)
        std::cout << "int";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, unsigned long>)
        std::cout << "ULONG";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, std::string>)
        std::cout << "string";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, float>)
        std::cout << "float";
    else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<Type, double>)
        std::cout << "double";
    else
        std::cout << "(error)";  // unhandled type, which cannot happen
                                 // by simply using std::visit.
}

// ...

    for (auto& e : lst)
        std::visit(overloaded{[](const auto& x) { PrintType(x); }}, e);
```