# Why is a struct field looking at uninitialized memory when using CRTP?

Tags: c++, crtp

I started experimenting with CRTP and ran into a very interesting problem that has been keeping me awake for two days now.

Using CRTP I declare 3 structures: `Column`, `Header` and `Footer`, which are inherited from `Widget`.

The `Column` structure takes the other widgets in the constructor and stores them in std::tuple, then in the `Render()` method, calls the `Render()` method of the widgets that are stored in `std::tuple`.

In `main()` you can see that the `Header` widget's title field is set, but during debugging the `Render()` method of the `Column` widget I noticed that the title field looks at uninitialized memory, so the program ends up with a segfault.

The code uses standard `c++20`.

Who can suggest what the problem is? Thanks in advance!

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
struct Widget {
    void Render() {
        static_cast<T*>(this)->Render();
    }
};

template<typename ...Args>
struct Column : public Widget<Column<Args...>> {
    Column(Widget<Args>... args)
        : children(std::forward<Widget<Args>>(args)...)
    {}

    void Render() {
        std::cout << "Column {" << std::endl;

        std::apply([](auto&... widgets){
            auto render = [](auto& widget){
                widget.Render();
            };

            (render(widgets), ...);
        }, children);

        std::cout << "}" << std::endl;
    }

private:
    std::tuple<Widget<Args>...> children;
};

struct Header : public Widget<Header> {
    void Render() {
        std::cout << "Header { title=" << this->title << " }" << std::endl;
    }

    std::string title;
};

struct Footer : public Widget<Footer> {
    void Render() {
        std::cout << "Footer {}" << std::endl;
    }
};

template<typename T>
void AplicationRun(Widget<T> widget) {
    widget.Render();
}

int main() {
    auto app = Column{
        Header{
            .title = "Title"
        },
        Column{},
        Footer{},
    };

    AplicationRun(app);

    return 0;
}
```

I tried using move sematic in the `Column` constructor but that didn't help.

Comment: Why does your lambda take `Widget<Args>...`? Do you know what object slicing is?

Comment: You could do something like this instead: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63743699/4641116 (not a solution to the OP question, but maybe an inspiration)

Comment: For C++17, just after the `Column` definition, add a `Column(struct allow_ctad_t)->Column<void>;` to avoid the compiler warning about CTAD.  (Something you lucky folks in C++20 land don't have to bother with.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument to the function

```
template<typename T>
void AplicationRun(Widget<T> widget) {
```

is a `Widget<Column>` which is **not** a `Column`. Unlike other languages you might be used to, this argument is not a reference to the object, but is in fact a whole object. To fit the `Column` object into this `Widget<Column>` argument the compiler only copies the `Widget<Column>` part, a common pitfall called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-object-slicing) because the argument is only a "slice" of the original object.

You could fix this by changing `Widget<T>` to `T`. However it would still make a copy of the `Column` object, which I suppose you don't want.

To avoid making a copy you can pass by reference: `Widget<T> &` or `T &`. Either one is okay, because the `Widget<T> &` parameter *can* be a reference to a `Column` object.

---

If passing by reference, you can also choose to use `Widget<T> const &` or `T const &` which prevents the function from modifying the object (and the `Render` function will need to be marked `const` so you can still call it). You don't need that in this small program if you don't want to, but it's common for programmers on bigger programs to restrict themselves like this because it helps to avoid mistakes (bugs).